# If $(4,-1)$ is on the graph of $f$, what point must be on the graph of $g$, where $g(x)= 2f(-2(x+1))-2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Given that $g(x)= 2f(-2(x+1))-2$ and the point $(4, -1)$ is on the graph of $f(x)$.
What point must exist for $g(x)$?  I don't know how to start this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: If the only thing you know is $f(4)$, then try making the inside of $f$ look like $4$; that is, set

$$-2(x + 1) = 4$$

Then solve for $x$ and evaluate $g(x)$.